# collect data in array

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

[image]

[image]

I want to sum the numbers of those with the same category name and I want to print.
sample: Edebiyat = 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
// ...


// Handling "grouping" and "summing" operations in "Collection" is much easier.
// Because of this, I convert "array" to "Collection".
$best_selling_categories = collect($best_selling_categories);

// It groups the data by the "category_name" field.
$best_selling_categories = $best_selling_categories->groupBy('category_name');

// It transforms the grouped category list into the sum of the group.
$best_selling_categories = $best_selling_categories->map(function ($categoryGroup){
    return collect($categoryGroup)->sum('number');
});

dd($best_selling_categories);

// Output:
//
// [
//    "Bilgisayar/Tablet" => 7
//    "Çocuk" => 5
//    "Elektronik" => 6
//    "Edebiyat" => 10
// ]
```

Comment: çok teşekkürler :)